# Create a group of elements JointJS

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I'm new with jointJS and I try to bind element together and to group them.
My aim is to clone a rect a the rect embedded in.
Is it possible with jointJS or do I have to create my embedded rect each single time? (and link them together)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `joint.dia.Cell.prototype.clone` with option `deep=true` ([docs](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element:clone)).

```
var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect();
var circle = new joint.shapes.basic.Circle();

graph.addCells([rect, circle])
rect.embed(circle);
// -> rect embeds circle

var clonesArray = e1.clone({ deep: true });
// -> clonesArray contains clone of rect and clone of circle.

graph.addCells(clonesArray);
// -> cloned rect embeds cloned circle
```